# How to add Django Language mode in CodeMirror Plugin of CKEditor?

Tags: django, ckeditor, codemirror

I'm using CKEditor wysiwyg for creating django templating. Therefore, I come across using codemirror plugin for CKEditor as [here](https://w8tcha.github.io/CKEditor-CodeMirror-Plugin/index.html). By following installation instruction, the following options available for config as refered [here](https://w8tcha.github.io/CKEditor-CodeMirror-Plugin/installation.html):

```
config.codemirror = {

    // Set this to the theme you wish to use (codemirror themes)
    theme: 'default',

    [.......................]

    // Define the language specific mode 'htmlmixed' for html  including (css, xml, javascript), 'application/x-httpd-php' for php mode including html, or 'text/javascript' for using java script only 
    mode: 'htmlmixed',

    [.......................]

     // Whether or not to show the showAutoCompleteButton button on the toolbar
    showAutoCompleteButton: true
};
```

However, as above mode options, the languages are limited to html, javascript, and php, that I could not use another language, for my case `Django`.

I tried to modify the default code mirror plugin of CKEditor at `<path to CKEditor>/Plugins/codemirror/plugin.js` to add somewhere possible for django language, yet it resulted only in code error.

So, how can I do to add Django language in codemirror plugin of CKEditor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror modes are not limited to `html, javascript, and php`, here is a list of all supported [language modes](https://codemirror.net/mode/)

Make sure you have the `Django` mode loaded along with `xml, htmlmixed` modes loaded in this order:

- xml mode: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.48.4/mode/xml/xml.js
- htmlmixed mode: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.48.4/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js
- django mode: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.48.4/mode/django/django.js

---

**Mode for HTML with embedded Django template markup.**:

```
mode: 'django'
```